# Calling web service requiring basic http authentication from a bpel process

Tags: security, netbeans, bpel, glassfish-esb

I am looking to call a web service requiring basic authentication from a bpel process. I have configured my wsdl as close to what the "net" says as possible but it still doesn't work. It makes the call but without the all important line in the header of the request.

Can anyone who has done this please help? Maybe an example or something?

See [here](http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=Securing%20Communications%20In%20Open%20ESB%20With%20Glassfish%20Realm%20Security) for some of the examples I've followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must have been a pebkac, I downloaded and example, copy and pasted into my code and it worked. Am very happy. I think it just need a good night's sleep :)

Comment: Hi, can you give the link for that example?